# SQL JOIN using a mapping table

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have three tables:

```
COLLECTION 
PERSON 
PERSON_COLLECTION
```

where `PERSON_COLLECTION` is a mapping table `id|person_id|collection_id`

I now want to select all entries in collection and order them by `person.name`.

Do I have to join the separate tables with the mapping table first and then do a join again on the results?

Comment: Can you show your table schema? Update your question please. Also indicate any referential integrity you have between the tables.

Comment: As a general* rule of joining tables, start with your largest/data tables, and work your way to the smallest/mapping tables.  Also, perform INNER joins before LEFT joins.  *NOTE: GENERAL rule.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
SELECT
    c.*,
    p.Name
FROM
    Collection c
    JOIN Person_Collection pc ON pc.collection_id = c.id
    JOIN Person p ON p.id = pc.person_id
ORDER BY p.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure without the table schema but, my take is:

```
SELECT
c.*,
p.*

FROM
Person_Collection pc
LEFT JOIN Collection c
ON pc.collection_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN Person p
ON pc.person_id = p.id

ORDER BY p.name
```

Answer (score 0):

The order you join won't break it but depending on which sql product you're using may effect performance.
You need to decide if you want ALL records from both/either table or only records which have a  matching mapping entry, this will change the type of join you need to use.