# Joining tables through a mapping table with a condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables, `product` and `category`, joined through a mapping table `product_category`.

```
*** product  ***
int id, varchar name, ... more columns

*** category ***
int id, varchar name

*** product_category ***
int product_id, int category_id
```

I want to select all of the products that are in a category with a certain name. I have seen the answer for [SQL JOIN using a mapping table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13478715/5743988), which leads me to create these working SQL queries, but **which one is best practice/more efficient?** (I'm not experienced in SQL)

Using an `AND` clause in the `JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    p.*
FROM
    category c
    JOIN product_category pc
        ON c.id = pc.category_id
        AND c.name = ?
    JOIN product p 
        ON p.id = pc.product_id
ORDER BY p.name
```

Or using a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT 
    p.*
FROM 
    category c
    JOIN product_category pc 
        ON c.id = pc.category_id
    JOIN product p 
        ON p.id = pc.product_id
WHERE
    c.name = ?
ORDER BY p.name
```

Or maybe there's another, even better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are virtually identical, and the most direct route to the data.

You have to establish the relationship of your tables in the `FROM` which you have done in both queries. Then you have to restrict what data is present in your result set using your `c.name = ?` condition, which you have done in both queries.

It is very likely that MySQL's optimizer will execute both of these queries in the exact same manner. To be sure, you can run `EXPLAIN` on both and see if there are any differences. For example:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT
    p.*
FROM
    category c
    JOIN product_category pc
        ON c.id = pc.category_id
        AND c.name = ?
    JOIN product p 
        ON p.id = pc.product_id
ORDER BY p.name;
```

[Read more about EXPLAIN here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html)

Lastly, the second one is easier to read so going that route will insure that whoever takes this over from you will have less of an urge to murder you in your sleep. Which is a good thing.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try out using `EXPLAIN` when I get home later today. I'll let you know!

Comment: Yes, after using `EXPLAIN`, both of the queries were identical. It transformed the `AND` clause into a `WHERE` clause on its own in the optimizer, so I'm definitely going with the more readable `WHERE` clause. Thanks again. You also helped me with how to solve my questions in the future :)