# joining through a mapping table - duplicate values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables as such and want to get pack details for each product. So I `left join` `productpacks` throughtable to `product` through `product.pack(FK) == productpacks.product_pack`.

Then I still need the details for the packs, so I join `productpacks.official_pack` based on the `product.pack == productpacks.product_pack` match to `packs.pack` and get the `volume` and `weight`.

```
     product         productpacks           packs
     -------         ------                 ----------
     name            product_pack           pack (PK)          
     pack (FK)       official_pack          info1
     customer        customer               info2
```

This seems to be returning duplicates of the `product` though using `LEFT JOIN`. How do I join to another table through a throughtable such as `productpacks`?

---

**Product**

```
product   |    pack    |    customer     |   time
--------------------------------------------------
product1       16oz         customer1       1:00
product1       16oz         customer1       2:00
product3       11oz         customer1       3:00
product4       16 OZ        customer2       4:00
```

**ProductPacks**

```
product_Pack   |    official_Pack      |  customer
--------------------------------------------------
16oz                Sixteen OZ            customer1
12oz                Twelve OZ             customer1
11oz                Eleven OZ             customer1
16 OZ               SIXTEEN OZ            customer2
```

**Packs**

```
pack           |   info1   |   info2
-----------------------------------
Sixteen OZ          12          Red
Twelve OZ           13          Blue
Eleven OZ           14          Green
SIXTEEN OZ          16          etc..
```

**Expected Output:**

```
product   |    pack    |    customer  |  time  |   pack       | info1 | info2
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
product1       16oz         customer1    1:00      Sixteen OZ    12     Red
```

**Actual Output:**

```
product   |    pack    |    customer  |  time  |   product_pack  | official_pack | customer | pack       | info1 | info2
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
product1       16oz         customer1    1:00    16oz           Sixteen OZ   customer1    Sixteen OZ    12     Red
product1       16oz         customer1    1:00    16oz           Sixteen OZ   customer1    Sixteen OZ    12     Red
```

SQL

```
SELECT * FROM product p
LEFT JOIN productpacks pp 
  ON p.customer = pp.customer
  AND p.pack = pp.product_pack
LEFT JOIN packs pk
  ON pp.official_pack = pk.pack
```

Comment: Please show some sample data and expected output.  It isn't obvious to me how to join together these tables.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen please see above

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Added the SQL snippet that I'm trying. It's returning duplicate products. I think it's because I'm left joining and returning matches for `ProductPacks`, then returning matches again for `Packs`, which also has matches in `Product`

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478715/sql-join-using-a-mapping-table, it seems I'm doing it correctly

Comment: Your query should be returning at least four rows.  Your `Product LEFT JOIN ProductPacks LEFT JOIN Packs` means that it will show a row for each Product at least once. Your result set shows only two rows. So there is something missing from your question.

Answer (score 0):

@Growler you're getting duplicates in your result because there are duplicates in your product table (at least in your example).

Comment: Okay please see above. I've made it more clear. It should return multiple products, but each row has a different timestamp. My results are coming back with two `1:00` timestamps, for which there only exists one instance in the `Product` table

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Matt do you see that it's including the mapping table results too?

Answer (score 0):

In table product since the time for product1 is 1:00 and 2:00 your query is returning the correct answer i.e 2 different rows because of time column difference which is correct. I think the result you have posted contains time 1:00 and 2:00 and not 1:00 and 1:00

Comment: It's returning 1:00 and 1:00

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the group by clause, cane you check the below query once:

```
SELECT p.product,p.pack,c.customer,p.time,pk.pack,pk.info1,pk.info2 
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN productpacks pp 
  ON p.customer = pp.customer
  AND p.pack = pp.product_pack
LEFT JOIN packs pk
  ON pp.official_pack = pk.pack
GROUP BY p.product,p.pack,c.customer,p.time,pk.pack,pk.info1,pk.info2 ;
```